# Fail2Ban keeps banning on restart

Tags: linux, centos7, fail2ban

I'm facing a confusing issue with Fail2Ban.

I run an older version which, upon restart of the Fail2Ban Daemon unbans all IP addresses.

I now have Fail2Ban version 0.9.3 installed on Centos 7. When I restart Fail2Ban, it re-bans the previously banned IP addresses. I do not want this to happen, and instead want all bans cleared on restart, which is the way it used to work.

I've set `dbfile = None` to prevent persistent banning and also set `dbpurgeage = 0` just to be safe.

But on restart any banned IP's get banned again.

Here's an excerpt from `/var/log/fail2ban.log` when a user gets banned via vsftpd:

```
2016-09-19 20:45:58,671 fail2ban.filter         [23752]: INFO    [vsftpd] Found xx.xx.xx.xx
2016-09-19 21:01:55,665 fail2ban.filter         [23752]: INFO    [vsftpd] Found xx.xx.xx.xx
2016-09-19 21:02:06,679 fail2ban.filter         [23752]: INFO    [vsftpd] Found xx.xx.xx.xx
2016-09-19 21:02:06,936 fail2ban.actions        [23752]: NOTICE  [vsftpd] Ban xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Then upon restarting Fail2Ban here's the last few lines of the log file:

```
2016-09-19 21:02:42,719 fail2ban.jail           [24213]: INFO    Jail 'vsftpd' started
2016-09-19 21:02:42,761 fail2ban.filter         [24213]: INFO    [vsftpd] Found xx.xx.xx.xx
2016-09-19 21:02:42,761 fail2ban.filter         [24213]: INFO    [vsftpd] Found xx.xx.xx.xx
2016-09-19 21:02:42,921 fail2ban.actions        [24213]: NOTICE  [vsftpd] Ban xx.xx.xx.xx
```

It seems to be re-scanning the log files and re-banning a previously banned user.

As I mention, this is not how it used to work in older versions of Fail2Ban - how can I revert to the previous functionality?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure. Most people _hated_ that it wasn't persistent, and _want_ the current behavior. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Occasionally a legitimate user will get banned - rather than try and figure out and confirm what their IP address is, it was easier just to restart fail2ban - that's the main reason really

Comment: So instead of unbanning the hapless user, you want to unban everything, including the bad actors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the use of dbfile means that `fail2ban` loses track of its read position in each file on restart and so reads the whole file leading to the behaviour you've observed.

Adding `tail` after the filenames in the `logpath` statements will tell `fail2ban` to start reading from end of file rather than starting at beginning. That should (I think) give the behaviour you want (or near enough). See [docs](https://www.mankier.com/5/jail.conf#Jail_Configuration_File%28s%29_%28jail.conf%29) for more detail. Relevant section is ...

> Optional space separated option 'tail' can be added to the
>   end of the path to cause the log file to be read from the end, else
>   default 'head' option reads file from the beginning

However, I'd agree with the implication of Michael Hampton's comment - the right way to deal with this is to reinstate the use of `dbfile` and use the unban functionality.

Comment: OK point taken.  We've been doing it this way for years so now it feels like a chore attempting to find out the user's IP address, attempting to find out if they're banned, and then unbanning them.  Previously we'd just re-load Fail2Ban and see if the user was able to get access again.  Quick and dirty I admit, but I guess we'll have to get used to unbanning them manually in the future.